# Install subfloor over existing hardwood

Tags: subfloor

I plan on installing a floating floor.  The current flooring is hardwood, but is quite beat up, patched and whatnot (It had been carpeted).  I thought about sanding and refinishing, but there are so many patches it would not look good.

To make sure I start with a flat surface, I was thinking I could install 1/2 plywood sub flooring over the existing hardwood.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why not just install the floating floor directly over the hardwood?  Is it because the hardwood isn't level?  If that's the case, I'm not sure plywood is the right fix.

Comment: Please revise to better describe what problem you're trying to solve. If the hardwood is not flat, explain how. Photos would be great.

Comment: The floor is basically level, but has high and low spots.  I looked into floor leveling compound, but the prep work for that, sealing the cracks and all, seemed to be more work than it was worth.  Is there a thicker underlayment that could be used instead of plywood?

Comment: If you place plywood (or similar materials) on an uneven surface, you'll still have peaks and valleys where the sheets join.  You'll also have some air spaces underneath, which will result in the plywood flexing when you walk on it.  The flexing may cause issues with the floating floor if it's severe enough.  Even if the flexing is minor, it could cause annoying squeaking sounds.  Check the floating floor manufacturer's instructions to see how flat the installation surface needs to be.  It should be able to tolerate a little bit of unevenness.